# What's the Chinese word for "bare-metal" (computer programming)?

Tags: translation

[Bare-Metal Programming](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/3745/bare-metal-programming)

> Bare-metal programming is a term for programming that operates without various layers of abstraction or, as some experts describe it, "without an operating system supporting it."

```
Example:

A: I made a nice motor controller with a STM32 MCU.
B: Interesting, what OS did you use?
A: No OS, bare metal.
```

The informal Chinese word for this `bare metal` seems to be `裸奔`.

Although this word is widely used and understood among the programming community, I find it hard to use on a more formal occasion.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Bare Metal` could be tanslated as `裸金属` literally, but it doesn't make sense for Computer Science. I prefer to translate is as `裸机` (`Bare machine`).

[Bare machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bare_machine)

> Bare machine (or bare metal), in computer parlance, means a computer
>   without its operating system.

Example from [youdao](http://dict.youdao.com/search?q=bare+machine&keyfrom=dict.index):

> A new remote boot technology based on IP storage area network was
>   designed, and the core technology of it is the firmware protocol stack
>   running under **bare machine** platform.
>
> 设计了一种基于IP存储区域网络的远程引导技术，该技术的核心是运行在**裸机**下的固件协议栈。

From [baidu](http://fanyi.baidu.com/?aldtype=85&keyfrom=alading&smartresult=dict&expand=1#en/zh/bare%20machine):

> For example, you might choose to allow the results from the virtual
>   machines to vary within 10 percent of the results from the **bare metal**
>   control machine.
>
> 例如，您可以选择允许来自虚拟机的结果与来自**裸机**控制机器的结果存在10%的偏差。

Answer (score 2):

The common translation seems to be

> 裸金属

which is just naked + metalic(s)

As in:

> 2015年5月19日 - (底层)系统底层开发:裸金属(bare metal)、...通常意义上所说的“系统编程”,往往是指中...

Taken from http://linux.cn/article-5462-2.html

Your suggested 裸奔 on the other hand just means “streak” as in running around naked.

Another example of 裸金属:

> 裸金属架构 (“Bare Metal” Architecture)

From [http://zhidao.baidu.com/question/482432974.html?fr=ala&word=裸金属&device=mobile&ssid=0&from=844b&uid=0&pu=usm@0,sz@1320_2001,ta@iphone_1_8.4_3_600&bd_page_type=1&baiduid=B0DC14BD4CFD809A8478494C15B38C6D&tj=zhidao_2_0_10_l1](http://zhidao.baidu.com/question/482432974.html?fr=ala&word=%E8%A3%B8%E9%87%91%E5%B1%9E&device=mobile&ssid=0&from=844b&uid=0&pu=usm@0,sz@1320_2001,ta@iphone_1_8.4_3_600&bd_page_type=1&baiduid=B0DC14BD4CFD809A8478494C15B38C6D&tj=zhidao_2_0_10_l1)

Comment: Terrible translation. Terms like that make me hate translated programming books.

Comment: 裸奔 means "running naked". :)

Answer (score -1):

It should mean, a computer without OS, no software, only hardware. In programming, it means the programmer directly operate the machine, the chips without drivers, operating systems, and any other software.